# unable to remove subst-ed drive

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, subst

machine: Windows 8 64bit, single user with admin rights

I've probably used subst to make a new Q: virtual drive for my C:\portableDrive folder. Now I can't see it when I type "subst" command in the cmd. The Q: is not a mapped drive (via "net use" command) neither is it present in the disk management. Where could be the problem?

screenshot - http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26413862/screengrab_20130915165557.png
edit: maybe similar issue to this one - [Unable to unmount "subst" drive](https://superuser.com/questions/550205/unable-to-unmount-subst-drive)

Comment: @Mokubai His space on Q: shows Drivespace and freespace (same as C). If it is the virtual Q-drive Office 2010 creates its not accessible and doesn't show space (according to the screenshot in that topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see in your screenshot you are running cmd (the command prompt) elevated (note the "Adninistrator" before the `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`). But if you did the original `subst` as a user it won't show in an elevated prompt.

Start cmd.exe as normal (click start/type cmd and choose cmd.exe with just the left click) and then do `subst` and you should see your Q. Then you can delete it with `subst q: /d`.

**Edit**:
If you didn't create the drive-letter with `subst` it is possible it is created by another program using the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices`. If your drive-letter is available for all users on this system it can be in there. (You will need a restart after changing it.) Although in my setup (Win7 ultimate) it was still visible by `subst` but it could not change/delete it (but perhaps it's no longer visible in Win8).

([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST))

Comment: nope, that's probably not a root cause, I've turned on full UAC, now my command prompt is started normally and subst returns nothing, see: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26413862/screengrab_20130915190024.png

Comment: And you can access Q and you verified it is a sub-directory on your C-drive? (probably yes, according to the drivespace in your first screen-shot)

Comment: yes, I can access Q: (regardless UAC) and the content changes are of course reflected to the real folder - C:\portableDrive

Comment: Can you remember doing the `subst` in the first place? If not it could be created by another program in a registry key. I updated my answer for this.

Comment: For further troubleshooting (if it's not the reg key): if you create or login as another user is the drive still there? Then it's not made with `subst`. Also i take it it will survives a full reboot. (Normal `subst` does not survive a reboot (unless it's executed on startup somewhere).

Comment: That's true, now I remember 1 year ago, creating this drive, being unsuccessful with subst (not persistent across reboots), I've used that exact registry key you mention in edited part of your answer.
Deleting that key and rebooting solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: admin vs regular user doesn't have access to the same subst virtual drives. remember to execute `subst` with no arguments to show what's currently mapped